# Time line with marked points, flipped curly brackets beneath using Tikz package

Tags: graphics, brackets

I have previously used the Tikz package for illustrations of nodes and paths in LaTeX, but I don't know where to start to make the figure illustrated below.

Could someone please give a rough setup on how to make a time line with marks, the flipped curly brackets below the time line, the brackets above the time line, and the dotted line from one of the brackets and down to the mark on the time line?

[image: figure]

Comment: Hi and welcome, you can always use TikZ for that. It is a great package coming with a pretty nice tutorial.

Comment: Someone downvoted the question without leaving a comment reasoning why. That's not very nice. But i thin i know the reason for downvoting. The question as is is not very good for the quality standards of our comunity and could simply be answered with »Yes«. In fact, there are multiple ways to do this (PSTricks, TikZ, asymptote). I guess, giving a minimal setup showing at least the line (that should be easy) would make the question better to some extent.

Comment: A direct answer: "Yes, it is indeed possible in LaTeX." Please provide more information about your LaTeX setup and what, if available, you've tried out so far if you hope to get specific suggestions.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have tried to provide more information - was this what you were thinking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is your first question, and since we are supposed to be nice to new comers, here is a more verbose code for you.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (10,0)node[below] {Time};    
    \node[scale=4,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=west,label=above:$a_i$] (ail) at (1,4) {[};
    \node[scale=4,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=west,label=above:$b_i$] (air) at (3,4) {]};
    \draw[dashed] (ail) -- +(0,-4)node[pos=1](a){};
    \draw[very thick] (a.north)--(a.south);
    \draw[very thick] (3,4pt) -- (3,-4pt);
    \draw[very thick] (9,4pt) -- (9,-4pt);
    \node[scale=4,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=west,label=above:$a_j$] (ajl) at (6,3) {[};
    \node[scale=4,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=west,label=above:$b_j$] (ajr) at (8,3) {]};
    \draw[dashed] (ajr) -- +(0,-3);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt},] ([yshift=-0.2cm]2.95,0)-- node[below=0.25cm]
         {$\check{S}_i$}([yshift=-0.2cm]a.center);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt},] ([yshift=-0.2cm]9,0)-- node[below=0.25cm]
         {$\hat{t}_{ij}$}([yshift=-0.2cm]3.05,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can actually draw the brackets unlike me. I have not used any particular position to put the ticks on the time line since I could not follow your pattern. This should serve as a starting point for you.