# How to draw horizontal curly braces under a timeline?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, brackets, line, chronology

I have drawn a timeline using following answer for [How draw multiple timelines one after another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584581/127048). Is it possible to add horizontal curly braces under the timeline along with its label?

Desired sketch is as follows:

[image]

---

code for an example timeline:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,0)node(a){} -- (11,0) node (b) {} ;
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,50,...,500}
  {
    \def \inBetSpace {1}
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\i*\inBetSpace-\inBetSpace,-2mm) node[below](n\i) {\x} -- ++(0,4mm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211952/time-line-with-marked-points-flipped-curly-brackets-beneath-using-tikz-package

Comment: have alook at the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,0)node(a){} -- (11,0) node (b) {} ;
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,50,...,500}
  {
    \def \inBetSpace {1}
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\i*\inBetSpace-\inBetSpace,-2mm) node[below](n\i) {\x} -- ++(0,4mm);
  }
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=6pt},] ([yshift=-1cm]2.95,0)-- node[below=0.25cm]
{Label-1}([yshift=-1cm]a.center);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=6pt},] ([yshift=-1cm]9,0)-- node[below=0.25cm]
{Label-2}([yshift=-1cm]3.05,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT using font size `\tiny` and `\scriptsize` with font `\texttt`

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,0)node(a){} -- (11,0) node (b) {} ;
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,50,...,500}
  {
    \def \inBetSpace {1}
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\i*\inBetSpace-\inBetSpace,-2mm) node[below](n\i) {\x} -- ++(0,4mm);
  }
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=6pt},] ([yshift=-1cm]2.95,0)-- node[below=0.25cm]
{\texttt{\tiny Label-1}}([yshift=-1cm]a.center);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=6pt},] ([yshift=-1cm]9,0)-- node[below=0.25cm]
{\scriptsize Label-2}([yshift=-1cm]3.05,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please have a look at the edit above

Comment: code is corrected now please

Comment: Thanks ! Do you use any GUI during drawing? Do you have any suggestion as book are tutorial for self-learnings?

Comment: book -- http://ctan.imsc.res.in/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf -- there is no gui in latex -- self learning