# How to draw a long arrow, please?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am a beginner to LaTex.

How to draw a long arrow like this?

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585896/how-to-draw-horizontal-curly-braces-under-a-timeline/585898#585898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are novice here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be loaded after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 8mm and 24mm,
    BC/.style = {% Brace Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, 
                    raise=3pt, amplitude=6pt},
                    very thick, pen colour={black}
                },
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {align=center}
                    ]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (8.8,0);
\node (a) [dot,label=below:text\\here] at (2.2,0) {};
\node (b) [dot,label=below:text\\here,
           right=of a] {};
\node (c) [dot,label=above:text\\here,
           right=of b] {};
%
\draw[BC]   (a.north) -- node[above=9pt] {text here} (b.north);
\draw[->]   (c) -- ++ (0,1.1) node[above] {text here};           
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Assendum:**

As @jsbibra noted in his comment below. OP probably like to reduce `\baselineskip` distance, i.e. distance between text lines. This can be changed by determine `\linespread`. For example, with

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 8mm and 24mm,
    BC/.style = {% Brace Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace,
                    raise=3pt, amplitude=6pt},
                    very thick, pen colour={black}
                },
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {align=center},
        font = \linespread{0.84}\selectfont % <-----------
                    ]
% image code
```

image become:

[image]

Comment: Exactly this. Many thanks.

Comment: @PedroPasserini, then you can up-vote and accept answer (by clicking on up-pen and check mark at top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: Okay many thanks. Answer accepted; answer useful.

Comment: do you mind if I ask you how to change the line spacing (i.e., where I have ``text here")? Many thanks.

Comment: @PedroPasserini, do you mean distance between dots? or distance between text and arrow? The first is determined by `node distance = 8mm and 24mm` where `8mm` is vertical distance (so far not used in answer) and `24mm` horizontal distance. You can change this distance as like to have. Distance of  `text here` is determined by `inner sep` of  node (default is 3pt), if you like bigger distance form nodes coordinate, determine it as is done at brace:  ` ... node[above=9pt] ...`. Tell me, which distance you like to change that I can prepare addendum to my answer.

Comment: I think OP means line spacing between `text` and `here` should be less

Comment: @jsbibra, you may be right. This can be easy changed/reduced, for example by adding `font = \linespread{0.84}\selectfont` to `tikzpicture` options. Thank you very much for the comment.

Comment: Yes I meant line spacing between text. Very helpful. Many thanks.