# How to add a segment piece to a textizpicture?

Tags: graphics

How to add the following (segment, text, and arrow):
[image: The segments and writing above them and also the arrow.]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Assuming you want to do this using `tikz` have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597049/image-drawing-in-latex/597072#597072) for how to do the braces (disclaimer, one of the answers is mine), the text should be simple to add with a node and the arrows with `\draw[->] ...`. Have a look at the [TikZ manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) or [this](https://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) minimal introduction.

Comment: If you get part way to drawing what you want add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). You will then be much more likely to get an answer. Without an MWE it is likely that the question will be closed before you get an answer.